# Rails: weird behavior when getting last record while ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 6 and I've noticed a strange behavior in Active Record when trying to get the latest record from a collection. Here is what I have:

**session.rb**

```
class Session < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :participations
end
```

**participation.rb**

```
class Participation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :session
end
```

When I'm trying to get the latest participation with:

```
Participation.order(created_at: :desc).last
```

The SQL query generated looks like:

```
SELECT "participations".*
FROM "participations"
ORDER BY "participations"."created_at" ASC
LIMIT $1
```

Note that I did `order(created_at: :desc)` but the SQL is using `ASC`.

However, if I change my code to:

```
Participation.order(created_at: :asc).last
```

The SQL query is doing the opposite (a `DESC`):

```
SELECT "participations".*
FROM "participations"
ORDER BY "participations"."created_at" DESC
LIMIT $1
```

Does anyone have an explanation as to why it behave this way ? Is it a Rails bug ?
Seems like using `last` with `order` is causing this issue. If I remove `last`, ActiveRecord is generating the correct SQL (using the correct order)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveRecord is optimizing the SQL statement for you. This

```
Participation.order(created_at: :desc).last
```

returns the same result as

```
Participation.order(created_at: :asc).first
```

But the latter statement is more efficient because it has to traverse fewer rows, so Rails generates SQL as if you had written it that way.